# Activating Modern layout on SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience

I attended a recent Microsoft tech event this week and in a recent demo noted that a SharePoint Online site was created which took the new Modern UI.

I've attempted to recreate this on my own tenancy but this has yielded a site that has the classic interface on it.  My current settings in the admin section are

1. OD4B Experience - New Experience
2. OD4B Sync Button - Show the button
3. Sync Client for SharePoint - Start the new client
4. SharePoint Lists and Libraries experience - New experience (auto detect)

These combined don't appear to have activated the new UI OR give me the option to activate it.  Looking to apply a new masterpage doesn't appear to have given me any new options either.

Am I missing this or has it yet to be rolled out fully?

Thanks in advance
Steven

Comment: Are you Set up the release option for the first release?

Comment: I tried the same yesterday (and this tenant had Modern earlier), either Microsoft blocked me completely from Modern Experiences  or something changed. Libraries that had Modern now show Classic

Comment: Hi @Steve, are you creating Sites from SharePoint Admin center? If so it will not have a modern UI through out, but definitely have modern pages. Modern sites are created from SharePoint welcome page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After Microsoft released the GA Drop of SPFx, which means Modern Sites are now available on all tenants. I tried to play around with it. The first thing for me was to create a new Modern Team site. So as a common practice I navigated to SharePoint Admin, and created a new site collection, to my surprise the UI was classic but had ability to create modern pages.

This was very confusing to me, then I read an article by Chris O'Brien [here](http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2017/03/provisioning-modern-pages-and-spfx-web-parts.html). In the second paragraph he has mentioned below words

> "As a reminder, any **SharePoint site that is attached to an Office 365
>   Group** is a modern site, and any old SharePoint Online site that has
>   existed for a long time now has modern pages (it’s the default now
>   when a new page is created)."

So to fulfill above condition i.e. *site attached to O365 group*. You can confirm below 2 things

1. On your SharePoint Admin's settings page (`https://yourtenant-admin.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/online/TenantSettings.aspx`), allow users to create sites. 
   [image]
2. Secondly navigate to SharePoint home page `https://yourtenant.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/sharepoint.aspx` and create sites. These will be modern ones.

**Note**: This is my experience, there can be other ways and work around.

Comment: If you do, is the standard Documents library Modern? The Site HomePage is Modern, that Documents library it created is not (in my case)

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman I just created a new team site. The home page is modern. Dint check the libs but will confirm it. Ideally if MS says it realsed globally, then it should but u never know bugs can be there.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a Modern site using the below url ( kinda like workaround):

```
https://tenantname.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/creategroup.aspx
```

This will create a team site with group.

This is what i view in my tenant, its set to first release for all users. But i think it should work on all tenants irrespective of the release preferences.

[image]

Reference -  [Create connected SharePoint Online team sites in seconds](https://blogs.office.com/2016/11/08/create-connected-sharepoint-online-team-sites-in-seconds/)

Also, if you go to the url:

```
https://tenantname.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/sharepoint.aspx
```

There you have the option to create "Modern" site:

[image]

Note - both these options (urls) bypass the policy settings. As of now every user is able to create these sites. So, do keep a watch on the storage quotas.

Comment: Hi Gautam, above link is giving me access denied in my tenant.

Comment: you can also try `https://tenantname.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/sharepoint.aspx` and check ?